# "no audio devices are installed" my HP pavilion dv6000 tells me, & there have been no changes in hardware

Tags: windows-7, laptop, audio

Does anyone know what the audio playback is, made for the hp dv6000 laptop? The laptop originally came with vista, but it had windows 7 on it when I got it. I installed windows 8 on it and when I did the upgrade to 8.1 there was no longer any audio capability. It tells me there is no device installed. I reinstalled windows 7 and no audio still. "No audio devices are installed" Can anyone help me with this, it has driven me mad!   ...and other than taking it apart...which I don't want to do...how do I find out which audio device{s} are in there...it says there are no audio devices found.

Comment: We need to first identify the device so we can point you to the right drivers (or enable you to identify what to download). Click "Start" -> type "Device Manager" -> open "Device Manager" -> You will have an uninstalled device (with a question mark next to it) that will probably be your soundcard (or a portion of it) -> Right click the device and click "Properties" -> Click the "Details" tab -> Find "Hardware Ids" in the dropdown -> Paste up the longest line (top) of the results box. This will tell us the device manufacturer and what the device is so we can try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install one of these drivers:

1. [sp59154.exe [43.27M]](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp59001-59500/sp59154.exe)
2. [sp57966.exe [42.95M]](ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp57501-58000/sp57966.exe)
3. [sp40170.exe [1/1, 22.41M]](http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp40001-40500/sp40170.exe)
4. [sp38899.exe [1/1, 18.28M]](http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp38501-39000/sp38899.exe)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have the drivers installed.  Go to HP's site and do there little java plug in and it will tell you what drivers you need.  I have an HP lap top and did the different OS thing as well.  A problem arises that HP's java plug-in may not find the driver for your hardware+OS.  In which case you have to figure out the right manufacture for the hardware (often times re-branded)  and down load the right drivers.